# Configuration Files For Web Applications

Tags: mvc, configuration

I am building a MVC application. This app has a core which is where all interfaces, abstract classes and operation logic are situated. It also contains a directory called module, this application is based in module. For example there is a module User which contains controllers, models and views (it does stuff related to user operations).

Am currently using json string for the configuration of my application. I have a route class that cheeks which controller belong to what model, it check is the module is active or if the controller is active and many other stuff.

So my question is? Apart from json and xml is there any other configuration formate out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two other formats that spring to mind are [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) and [INI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file). YAML is used by Google App Engine to [control its routing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig?hl=en), so you might want to look at that first. Lots of languages also have their own configuration formats, such as Perl's [Config::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~sherzodr/Config-Simple-4.59/Simple.pm) and Java's [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html).